# Job failed for Integration in GitLab (jq: error (at <stdin>:9): Cannot iterate over null (null))

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, salesforce, integration, gitlab-ci

I am working in GitLab and I connect my GitLab with salesforce. I created a Gitlab-ci.yml in my project directory. Now when I execute the pipeline in GitLab testing phase pass but failed in integration part at following code `PACKAGE_VERSION_JSON="$(eval sfdx force:package:version:list --concise --released --packages $PACKAGE_NAME --json | jq '.result | sort_by(-.MajorVersion, -.MinorVersion, -.PatchVersion, -.BuildNumber) | .[0]? // ""')"`

Can anyone tell me how can I resolve this issue. ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have generated package in the same org,which you are using for git lab authentication.